# What's the best DB design to model this case of super type/ sub type?

Tags: database, database-design, modeling, subtype, supertype

Imagine that you have to model incidents. There's four types of incidents (could be more). They all share some characteristics. So, the main shared fields would be in a supertype table called *incidents* and there will be one table per incident-type having incident_id as a FK. I could even have a *incident type* table to help me enforce that one incident id will be of one type only. This is all very text book, BUT, I'd like to know what's the best way to model the case when 3 of these incident types share a subset of fields and these fields are mandatory to them (so I can't put then in the supertype table, can I?). On top of that, some of those fields shared only by 3 of the incident types have a limited set of values (i.e. types of rock) and that's a typical look-up table.

So, should I repeat all these fields in the 3 incident tables and have a look-up table being Foreign keyed to these 3 tables? Should I have intermediary tables?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: Best thing to do would be to create a basic version of the tables and start adding data, writing queries or building screens on them (if that is part of your task). Try to minimize duplication of data while retaining ability to easily create and use the data. That should give you an idea of which will be best - there are always good and bad parts of any solution